# filter the file type with the file upload control

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

how to filter the file type with the file upload control in asp.net & c#.net

for example on clicking the browse button of the file upload control ,it should open browse file dialog with only excel file types.

how is it possible

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this is the answer from the other forum

I think it 's easy to realise it if you use C# (or VB,net) and .net fileupload control. you may define file types in arraylist "allowedExtensions".

```
string upload_Image(FileUpload fileupload, string ImageSavedPath)
{
    FileUpload fu = fileupload;  
    string imagepath = "";
    if (fileupload.HasFile)
    {
        string filepath = Server.MapPath(ImageSavedPath);  
        String fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fu.FileName).ToLower();
        String[] allowedExtensions = { ".gif", ".png", ".jpeg", ".jpg" };
        for (int i = 0; i < allowedExtensions.Length; i++)
        {
            if (fileExtension == allowedExtensions[i])
            {
                try
                {
                    string s_newfilename = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() +
                        DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() +
                        DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() +                           DateTime.Now.Second.ToString() +  fileExtension; 
                        fu.PostedFile.SaveAs(filepath + s_newfilename);

                   imagepath = ImageSavedPath + s_newfilename;
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   Response.Write("File could not be uploaded.");
               }

           }

       }

   }
   return imagepath;
}
```

Comment: sorry to say its a pathetic code above. not efficient. s_newfilename = DateTime.Now.ToString(); :)

Comment: don't loop through the acceptable extensions, just if(allowedExtensions.contains(extension)) is fine

Comment: @LojiSmith What exactly do you think the contains function does? It loops through the iteration. there is nothing wrong with the above code except for the fact that they aren't breaking out of the loop once they find a match...

Comment: StephenKelzer: that is a sequential search, there are searchs way more efficient that that one so I doubt that is the one used by the Contains function.

Answer (score 24):

It works perfectly!

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" accept=".xls, .xlsx"/>
```

Comment: Wow, that was easy!

Comment: This does not prevent to upload a different type by the user. In Chrome, it hides other extension files from the user's file browser.

Answer (score 3):

I refer to post # [ASP.NET - Limit file upload available file types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491257/asp-net-limit-file-upload-available-file-types)

Using RegularExpressionValidator can solve the problem easily. No serverside code is necessary for the checking of the extension anymore. Copy & Paste this code

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="uplValidator" runat="server"   

  ControlToValidate="FileUpload1" ErrorMessage=".mp3, .mp4 & wma formats are allowed"

 ValidationExpression="(.+\.([Mm][Pp][3])|.+\.([Mm][Pp][4])|.+\.([Ww][Mm][Aa]))">

</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible with `<input type="file"` control.

I've heard about `SWFUploader` that allows to define extensions for files to upload, but this is a flash-based component.

And even if you use `SWFUploader`, nothing will prevent you against typing `*.*`, and selecting any file to upload.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **C1Upload** from ComponentOne to do this. It has support for file type and size validation. Keep in mind, you will want to also validate on the server since file extensions can easily be changed to mismatch their actual type. This is a standard in any validation practice: validate in the UI layer then validate at the BL layer and preferably validate at the DL too. Here is a demo of the [ASP.NET AJAX upload control](http://demo.componentone.com/aspnet/controlexplorer/C1Upload/Validation.aspx) with built-in validation.

Another cool thing about this control is that is **supports multiple upload files** and **shows upload progress**!

Answer (score 0):

when using Angular File Upload , this way you ca pass filters to uploder

.html file

```
<input type="file" nv-file-select uploader="uploaderImages" />
```

.js file:

```
$scope.uploaderImages.filters.push({
    name: 'imageFilter',
    fn: function (item/*{File|FileLikeObject}*/, options) {
        var type = '|' + item.type.slice(item.type.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) + '|';
        return '|jpg|png|jpeg|bmp|gif|'.indexOf(type) !== -1;
    }
});
```