# RequiredFieldValidation for FileUpload

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, requiredfieldvalidator

My code looks like this:

```
 <asp:Label ID="importLabel" runat="server" Text="Update Prices" CssClass="fieldlabel" />
                <asp:FileUpload ID="importFileUpload" runat="server" />
```

I need to add a required field validator to only accept .csv files.  How would I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: [ASP.NET - Limit file upload available file types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491257/asp-net-limit-file-upload-available-file-types)

Comment: Thank you sir!  I'll update to show what was done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="uplValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="importFileUpload" ErrorMessage="Only .csv files are allowed" 
                            ValidationExpression="(.+\.([Cc][Ss][Vv]))" />
```

Added this REV to get it to work!