# Filter File extension With FileUpload

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I am writing an asp.net web app which involves the use of the `FileUpload` control.

Right now, this particular `FileUpload` control only expects .zip or .gz file types.  If an incorrect type of file is uploaded, An error message is displayed to the user.  This functionality is already implemented.

What I want to do is to filter the visible file types that the user sees when he clicks on "browse".

You may have seen a file opening dialog resembling the following.
[image]

I've circled the area that represents the file extension filter.

This is a feature so common that I expected it to be built in to the current `FileUpload` Control but after some searching online, I've found some posts that say it can't be done.

Those posts were from 2009, more than 2 years ago.

Now, My question is:  does the current Asp.Net 4.0 support this feature?, and if it doesn't, do you know of any simple solution to get the functionality that I want.

**I would like to again point out that I am able to validate whether or not the user chooses a supported file type.  All I'm looking for is a cosmetic change, that will filter out unneeded file types in the open file dialog.**

Comment: this is available for desktop applications , but not for web applications yet !

Comment: The accepted answer on the so-called "duplicate" looks like it does validation, but not filtering.

Comment: I agree with the answer on the duplicate not being what you are looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe it is not possible.Filter by file type in browser is not control by asp.net.It is a browser functionality.

This question already asked in stackoverflow.Please click 
[filter the file type with the file upload control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506821/filter-the-file-type-with-the-file-upload-control)

Comment: I saw that, but Microsoft has released their .Net Framework 4.0 A few weeks after that question was asked, and after most of the answers were posted.

Comment: This answer below works for a subset of browsers:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/23589176/12601

Answer (score 25):

You can try the below code.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="UploadFile" accept="image/*" multiple="false" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" />
```

It works with modern browsers.

Do not forget to validate the extensions using code behind procedures.

Answer (score 9):

To select images in fileupload control..

hope it will help you

```
asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rexp" runat="server" ControlToValidate="fupProduct"
     ErrorMessage="Only .gif, .jpg, .png, .tiff and .jpeg"
     ValidationExpression="(.*\.([Gg][Ii][Ff])|.*\.([Jj][Pp][Gg])|.*\.([Bb][Mm][Pp])|.*\.([pP][nN][gG])|.*\.([tT][iI][iI][fF])$)"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible on client-side!
But, remember to do the server-side validation.

This two links show it:
http://aspalliance.com/1614_Adding_Filter_Action_to_FileUpload_Control_of_ASPNET_20.all
http://www.codeshode.com/2011/07/validate-file-extension-for-aspnet.html

Comment: Good answer @Stephan. Too many people forget that this kind of work is done in the browser, not on the server.

Answer (score -1):

you can create validate file extension from the ASP.NET FileUpload Control

I believe you could go for this solution

[Validate File Extension for ASP.NET FileUpload Control](http://www.codeshode.com/2011/07/validate-file-extension-for-aspnet.html)

Comment: In two places of my question, I've mentioned that I already am able to do that kind of validation.  That is not the functionality that I'm asking about