# How to Filter by file type

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload

So I have a FileUpload control how to make it filter only for excel files? Now it has option All Files (*.*) and I need to be like (.xls) and (.xlsx) only

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [filter the file type with the file upload control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506821/filter-the-file-type-with-the-file-upload-control)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/700593/FileUpload-Filter-File-Type-File-Extension-File-Si

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
         var validFilesTypes = ["bmp", "gif", "png", "jpg", 
         "jpeg", "doc", "docx", "xls", "xlsx", 
         "htm", "html", "rar", "zip", "txt", "pdf"];
        $('.s').change(function () {
            CheckExtension(this);

            validateFileSize(this);

        });
        function CheckExtension(e) {
            /*global document: false */


            var file = e;
            var path = file.value;

            var ext = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, path.length).toLowerCase();
            var isValidFile = false;
            for (var i = 0; i < validFilesTypes.length; i++) {
                if (ext == validFilesTypes[i]) {
                    isValidFile = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!isValidFile) {
                e.value = null;
                alert("Invalid File. Unknown Extension Of Tender Doc" + 
                "Valid extensions are:\n\n" + validFilesTypes.join(", ")); 
            }
            return isValidFile;
        }

        function validateFileSize(e) {
            /*global document: false */
            var file = e;
            var fileSize = file.files[0].size;
            var isValidFile = false;
            if (fileSize !== 0 && fileSize <= 25214400) {
                isValidFile = true;
            }
            if (!isValidFile) {
                e.value = null;
                alert("File Size Should be Greater than 0 and less than 25 mb");
            }
            return isValidFile;
        }
    });

</script>
```

and call it like this:

```
<asp:fileupload id="FileUpload1" CssClass="s" runat="server"></asp:fileupload>
```

or add it at code behind:

```
FileUpload1.CssClass = "s";
```

Comment: Proudly found elsewhere: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/700593/FileUpload-Filter-File-Type-File-Extension-File-Si

Comment: OK this will check for file extension but what I want is to filter the dialog box with only xls

Comment: I don't see a way.  Sorry.  Actually did some research - even the ajax toolkit does not support file type.  I assume sandbox, etc.

Comment: I didn't find a way too I also did some research that is why I posted here maybe there is a way done by someone but no luck till now...

Comment: There are some articles about using Flash, but I wouldn't do it that way.  Even if you use a flash applet for the actual file picker only.  Out of my skillset, though.  Good luck - sorry I could not be more help.

Comment: Thanks for your suggested answer. If you like my question please up vote it.